# error: POST http://localhost:3000/api/createProductCategory 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to insert data into a table using POST method for that I have a angular service function

```
angular.module("productCategoryModule")
.factory("productCategoryService",productCategoryService);

productCategoryService.$inject = ['$http'];

function productCategoryService($http){
    return {
        createProductCategory:function(productCategory){
            console.log("createProductCategory in service called",productCategory);
            return $http.post('/api/createProductCategory',
                {
                    categoryName:productCategory.categoryName,
                    details:productCategory.categoryDetails
                }
            );
        },
        getAllProductCategories:function(){
            return $http.get('/api/getAllProductCategory');
        }
    }
}
```

and at server side I have

```
function productCategoryRouteConfig(app){
    this.app = app;
    this.routeTable = [];
    this.init();
}

productCategoryRouteConfig.prototype.init = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.addRoutes();
    this.processRoutes();
}

productCategoryRouteConfig.prototype.processRoutes = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.routeTable.forEach(function(route){
        if(route.requestType == 'get'){
            //console.log("requestType",route.requestType)
            self.app.get(route.requestUrl,route.callbackFunction);
        } else if(route.requestType == 'post'){
            //console.log("requestType",route.requestType);
            self.app.post(route.requestUrl,route.callbackFunction);
        } else if(route.requestType == 'delete'){

        }

    });
}

productCategoryRouteConfig.prototype.addRoutes = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.routeTable.push({
        requestType: 'get',
        requestUrl: '/createProductCategory',
        callbackFunction: function(req, res){
            res.render('createProductCategory',{title:'Create Product Category'});
        }
    });

    self.routeTable.push({
        requestType: 'post',
        requestUrl: '/api/createProductCategory',
        callbackFunction: function(req, res){
            console.log("Post called");
            //res.render('createProductCategory');
            console.log("req.body",req.body);
            var productCategoryDb = require('../database/productCategoryDb');
            // console.log("productCategoryDb post",productCategoryDb);
            // console.log("hello from createProductCategory post");
            // console.log("req.body",req.body);

            // productCategoryDb.productCategoryDb.createProductCategory(req.body, function(status){
            //  if(status)
            //      res.json(status);
            //  console.log(status);
            // });
        }
    });

    self.routeTable.push({
        requestType: 'get',
        requestUrl: '/viewProductCategory',
        callbackFunction: function(req, res){
            res.render('viewProductCategory',{title:'View Product Category'});
        }
    });

    self.routeTable.push({
        requestType: 'get',
        requestUrl: '/api/getAllProductCategory',
        callbackFunction: function(req, res){
            console.log("hello from getAllProductCategory");
            var productCategoryDb = require('../database/productCategoryDb');
            console.log("productCategoryDb",productCategoryDb);
            // productCategoryDb.productCategoryDb.getAllProductCategories(
            //  function (productCategories){
            //      console.log("productCategories",productCategories);
            //      res.json({productCategories : productCategories});
            //  }
            // );
        }
    });
}

module.exports = productCategoryRouteConfig;
```

when I click on the button on client side I get this error

**POST http://localhost:3000/api/createProductCategory 500 (Internal Server Error)**

I am using Node express mysql and angular.

There are three files in me database folder.

1.connectionString.js

```
var mysqlConnectionString = {
    connectionString:{
        host:'localhost',
        user:'root',
        password:'root',
        database:'vidzy'
    }
}

//module.exports = mysqlConnectionString;
exports.mysqlConnectionString = mysqlConnectionString;
```

2.connection.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var mysqlConnectionString = require('/home/ep-3/node-express/yt_tutorial/database/connectionString.js');
var connectionStringProvider = {
    getSqlConnection:function(){
        var connection = mysql.createConnection(mysqlConnectionString.mysqlConnectionString.connectionString);

        connection.connect(function(err){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            } else{
                console.log("connection was successful");
            }
        });

        return connection;
    },
    closeSqlConnection:function(currentConnection){
        currentConnection.end(function(err){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            } else{
                console.log("Disconnected");
            }
        })
    }
}

exports.connectionStringProvider = connectionStringProvider;
```

3.productCategoryDb.js

```
var connectionProvider = require('/home/ep-3/node-express/yt_tutorial/database/connection.js');
var productCategoryDb = {

    createProductCategory : function(productCategory, onSuccessful){

        var insertStatement = 'INSERT INTO productcategory SET?';

        var category = {
            categoryName : productCategory.categoryName,
            Details : productCategory.details,
            isValid : productCategory.isValid,
            CreatedDate : new Date()
        }

        var connection = connectionProvider.connectionStringProvider.getSqlConnection();

        if(connection){

            connection.query(insertStatement, category, function(err, result){

                if(err){

                    console.log(err);
                }

                onSuccessful({status : 'Successful'});
                console.log(result); 
            });

            connectionProvider.connectionStringProvider.closeSqlConnection(connection);
        }
    },

    getAllProductCategory : function(callback){
        var connection = connectionProvider.connectionStringProvider.getSqlConnection();
        var selectStatement = 'SELECT * FROM productcategory';

        if(connection){
            connection.query(selectStatement, function(err, rows, fields){
                if(err){ through err; }
                console.log(rows);
                callback(rows);
            });
        }
    }
}

exports.productCategoryDb = productCategoryDb;
```

Comment: The absolute first thing you do when you encounter a 500 Internal Server Error, is always to check the server’s error logs.

Comment: Can you ensure that the localhost server is working properly? User CURL or any other tool to generate the same request, and try it out first.

Comment: @CBroe I get
GET /libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css 304 9.907 ms - -
GET /libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js 304 9.438 ms - -
GET /libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 304 9.309 ms - -
GET /libs/angular/angular.min.js 304 9.276 ms - -
GET /javascripts/app/productCategory/productCategoryModule.js 304 9.230 ms - -
GET /javascripts/app/productCategory/productCategoryController.js 200 5.135 ms - 569
GET /javascripts/app/productCategory/productCategoryService.js 200 7.232 ms - 586
GET /libs/angular/angular.min.js.map 304 0.459 ms - -Post called
req.body undefined

Comment: could you post your error message stack trace by updating your question??

Comment: @daniel.. I get only the error that I mentioned in the question. I spent my whole day for solving this problem. I figured out something that the problem is with the require function. The app crashes on var productCategoryDb = require('../server/database/productCategoryDb'); I have also tried changing the path here.

Comment: @GDabhi    so if you comment this variable do you still get an error?

Comment: @GDabhi          Also have you missed the `.js` extension on purpose for this line of code `require('../server/database/productCategoryDb');`

Comment: @daniel no I don't get any error if I comment the this variable, even If I pass a constant string as exprots.productCategoryDb = "Hello" I don't get any error. Also I didn't missed .js extenstion.

Comment: could you post your code for `productCategoryDb` by updating your question?

Comment: okk, I'll do that.

Comment: Could u confirm if it is working, if you change `require('../database/productCategoryDb');` to `require('../database/productCategoryDb.js');` and include `module.` before each `exports` in the 3 files you included.  It would be nice if you could attach a screenshot of your command prompt when that 500 server error occurs

Comment: @daniel require('..database/productCategoryDb') is working fine. I commented all my code and I was trying to console.log every step in the code. I found that mysql connected successfully but the main problem arrives on connection.query('Select * from productcategory',function(){..}); So now I am focusing on this issue.

Comment: alright, I got an error on my code when I removed `.js` extension and `modules.` from my code. That's why I asked you for a verification

Comment: @daniel thank you for your time. I have solved this problem. There were two errors in my code. 1. I by mistake typed  through instead of throw and 2. req.body was undefined because I was calling my route before app.use(bodyparser.json());

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it solved `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have included the module `body-parser`.

It seems the code you posted here to be the same as the tutorial I have been following.

Your code seems to be fine except I don't know what your code in `app.js` looks like.

I have verified that I get the console response for *req.body* as `undefined` when I comment out the module `body-parser`.

Comment: body-parser module is included by default.

Comment: calling the route should be after calling app.use(bodyparser.json())

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but in my case there was a node-modules function that increments id for each POST I made and i forgot to add id in my DTO..and now it's working; maybe it's not your case since u are using mysql but I'll post the answer anyway, maybe some1 will resolve his error thank to this help